# Counting steps and O-notation

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

How many steps do these two methods each have and how do I count them when I'm going for the worst case in both methods? I have read tons of articles on how to calculate the O-notation (smallest O-Notation amount in this case), but have no idea how it works. I get what the programms do but can someone help me with counting its steps and calculating the O-Notation in the worst case?

```
static int methode1(int[] arr) { 
    int min = 100; 
    int minidx = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
        if(arr[i]<min) { 
            minidx = i; 
        } 
    } 
    return minidx; 
}

static int methode2(int n) { 
    int count = 2; 
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++) { 
        for(int j=n; j>i; j--) { 
            count++; 
        } 
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Method 1

if I denote the length of the array (the number of elements in it) with *n*,
this loop will do *n* iterations. At every iteration an "if" is executed and sometimes an assignment. In any case there'll be an addition to get to the next item in the table. So we have something like 2-3 operations per element. The complexity is O(*n*). (Which means that there exists a natural number *p*, such that the number of operations is smaller than *p* * *n*, for all *n*. In our case, something like *p* = 5 would definitely work).

edit: To clarify the idea a little more: this is like in every iteration there's exactly 1 complex operation that consumes at most *p* time units.
O(*n*) means that the algorithm will execute at most *n* of these complex operations. Hence, the running time of the algorithm only depends on *n*.

2. Method 2

In this case you have one loop counting from 1 to *n*. These are *n* operations. For each of this steps you have another loop counting from *n* to 1, which are also *n* operations. Within the second loop there's only an increment operation.

So we have *n* * *n* increment operations within the inner loop, *n* * *n* decrement operations to do the inner loop, and another *n* increment operations to do the outer loop. This makes a complexity of O(*n*^2).

Comment: So O(n) ís the actual solution in moethod 1 for the big o-notation or is there anything else I really need to take into consideration?

Comment: Yes, O(n) is the solution for method1. O(n^2) is the solution for method2. Nothing else to consider. If the code is translated to machine code, there'll be a few more instructions per iteration, but that would only enlarge the *p*, not the complexity. (*p* might be 30 or even 100, but that would also be true for *n* = Googolplex).

Comment: Ok thanks, but can you tell me how many steps each program has in total? Talking about method 1, am I right with saying there are 202 steps without the return? setting an integer twice + the loop with another loop in it

Comment: You can't know the exact number of steps, but you can find an upper bound. In method1 you'll have *n* additions, *n* retrievals and *n* comparisons, just to perform the loop. Then you have *n* retrievals and *n* comparisons to perform the *n* if-statements. Last but not least you'll have *n* assignments. So we have 6 *n* operations. But this also depends on many other factors like processor architecture and compiler  quality.

Comment: Oh, and since you don't know *n*,  you definitely can't calculate a number of 202 operations. 6 *n* is pretty good, but I forgot to count the jump operations (jump back to the start of the loop), which adds another *n*. And it is very possible that memory contents is stored within a register in order to eliminate one memory access. This yields a different timing, but might require more operations.
This actually shows the power of the Big-O notation. Algorithms can be compared without the exact knowledge of the executing platform.

Comment: So I also can't tell n even though the program comes to an end after it has reached the maximum that can be set for minidx?

Comment: correct. Even if your array is sorted in descending order, which means that the first assignment of minidx is also the last one, the loop will still process all other elements of your array. Hence if your array has 1,000,000 entries, the number of operations performed will be some multiple of 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are no worst cases to consider for both of your methods, since there are no conditional exit in both of them.

Next, first one, while you seeking for them minimal element in the array (which most likely not ordered) you have to literally consider checking each one of the elements to find the minimal one, hence complexity will be `O(n)`.

Regarding second one, you have two nested loops, for first iteration of the outer loop you are doing `n` iteration within inner, for second you are doing `n - 1`, and etc... E.g.

`n, n - 1, n - 2, ..., 1`

which turns to be arithmetic series and sums up to `n*(n+1)/2`, in in big-O notation is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be methode1 - O(arr.length), methode2 - O(n^2).

You have `for` loops inside the methods. You can count (calculate) the number of times the code inside the loops executes. In the second case there's a loop nested inside another loop. In cases like that, the number of executions equals the number of executions in the first loop, times the number of executions in the second loop.